# Mongoose how to sort array of objects returned from query

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  local: {
    email: {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true, lowercase: true, trim: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
  },
  username: {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true},
  Items: [{
    name: {type: String, trim: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  }]
});
```

And I'm using the following query to retrieve all of the items:

```
User.findById(req.user.id, 'Items -_id', (err, user) => { ... });
```

which returns the following:

```
{ Items: 
   [ 
     { name: 'test1',
       _id: 58c70800a03d09a31bb7fc17,
       createdAt: Mon Mar 13 2017 20:58:40 GMT+0000 (GMT) },
     { name: 'test2',
       _id: 58c70826a03d09a31bb7fc18,
       createdAt: Mon Mar 13 2017 20:59:18 GMT+0000 (GMT) } 
   ] 
}
```

**My question is:** How can I edit my mongoose query to return objects inside `Items` array sorted in descending order based on `createdAt` property? i.e. so that `test2` appears above `test1`.

(some additional info, the items array on average will be of length 3-10 per user and i'm using Nodejs as the backend, for this reason, would sorting the array on the app side be bearable because of its small size or too inefficient due to Nodejs single threaded nature?), Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to match your `_id`, unwind `Items` array, perform a descending sort and project only `Items` field :

```
User.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "_id": new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c7fa6987200dfc592d088c")
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$Items"
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "Items.createdAt": -1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "Items": {
            "$push": "$Items"
        },
        "_id": 1
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "Items": 1
    }
}], function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: this solution returns the user id for every object inside Items array, how do I exclude the user id from the query result? And also is this query more efficient than doing it client side side with node? Thanks

Comment: Add `"_id":0` in the project stage to exclude _id. Aggregation is a mongodb  feature, it's much more efficient than doing it in nodejs

Comment: Thanks a lot, also is it possible to format it the same way as the output in my original question? So it's just an array containing objects, because now it returns an array with objects containing 'Items' key for every object? Thanks

Comment: Use a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), see my updated answer

Comment: The returned value is an array containing an object that contains all individual objects within 'Items', but the original output I mentioned in my question, was returning an object pointing to an array containing individual objects within 'Items', how do I edit your answer to change it to that? Thanks

Comment: Because with the current return value I have to do: res[0].Items on the application side before sending it to the client